# Sockets not working in release build React Native

Tags: react-native, sockets, websocket

I'm working on a project where I require sockets. So I implemented a socket connection and was working on debug but not in release build.

I need to get sockets working on release build without using socket.io.

**I'm using React Native : 0.61.5
And internet permission is mentioned in manifest file.**

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned on Github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24361

Make sure your config.urlServer is not an HTTP endpoint but should be HTTPS. Latest RN versions target recent Android SDK that blocks insecure HTTP connections automatically

If anyone is facing the same issue, because of the "http" just add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in  tag in android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

and you should be good.